# POEdit encodings issues

Tags: encoding, gettext, poedit

I'm using PoEdit to create my `messages.mo` file to be used in my `php` web app.

I checked my encoding is `UTF-8` and still, my accents are not showing (e.g. "é", "è", ...). Actually, both source and target files are defined with UTF-8...

Here's the code I use to enable `gettext`:

```
<?php
    $dir = "../locale";
    $lang="fr_FR";
    $domain="messages";
    putenv("LANG=$lang");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
    bindtextdomain ($domain, $dir);
    textdomain ($domain);
    echo gettext("TEST 1") . "\n";
    echo __("Test 2"); // works if using gettext("Test 2");
?>
```

EDIT: I also add here the header of my page, stating I should be using UTF-8...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

EDIT 2: Here a [link to the po file](https://www.eswys.ch/StackOverflow/messages.po). Also, I try to copy-paste the result here

> R�gle plurielle 1 accessible en �criture.

I should get

> Règle plurielle 1 accessible en écriture.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It's really not possible to determine what mistake you made where when you omit crucial information like the PO or MO file itself or even what it means that "accepts are not showing" (omitted? changed into the "base" character? garbled?). Generally speaking: stick to UTF-8 *everywhere* (source code, Poedit, server, HTML output) and you'll be fine.

Comment: @VáclavSlavík you are right, my bad. I added some additional details - it SEEMS to me I am using UTF-8 everywhere. Maybe one of my settings to compile the `.mo` file is wrong? I'm just no expert and have no clue where to seek..!

Comment: That file is obviously not the one from your example above. No, compiling MOs doesn't change encoding. Perhaps PHP is doing conversion and you told it, in your code, to use fr_FR locale, not fr_FR.UTF-8.

Comment: @VáclavSlavík You ROCK - I was using fr_FR and changing to fr_FR.UTF-8 did the trick... I'd be glad to know why this is, though...!